# How to merge arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

How to merge these two arrays using JavaScript:

```
[{"id1":"value1","id2":"value2"}]
[{"id3":"value3","id4":"value4"}]
```

Into this:

```
[{"id1":"value1","id2":"value2","id3":"value3","id4":"value4"}]
```

Comment: You need to add some example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function.

Either by adding the key/values from `b` into `a`:

```
function merge(a, b) {
    for (var p in b[0]) {
      a[0][p] = b[0][p];
    }
    return a;
}

merge(a, b);
```

Or by using a native array function like [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function merge2(a, b) {
    return b.reduce(function (el) {
        return el;
    }, a);
}

console.log(merge2(a, b));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z775y9ak/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Just use the built-in Javascript Array .concat() method.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

```
var a = ["id1","value1","id2","value2"]
var b = ["id3","value3","id4","value4"]
var c = a.concat(b)
//c is now  ["id1","value1","id2","value2","id3","value3","id4","value4"]
```

Comment: concat result is:[{"id1":"value1","id2":"value2"]["id3":"value3","id4":"value4"}]

Comment: Take another look at the question.